# How to place a 3D model from a local file path on gps coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, core-location

I'm using Project Dents ARKit + CoreLocation Pod to place a 3D model from a local file path at specific gps coordinates in the real world. I'm able to see my 3d model in AR. However, it seems like it's not fixed to the coordinates since the model moves with the camera and doesn't stick to the given gps location when I move away.

Here's what I've tried

```
sceneLocationView.run()
view?.addSubview(sceneLocationView)
    
// Config
self.sceneLocationView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
self.sceneLocationView.showsStatistics = true
    
// Coordinates of where the model should be placed
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: arConfig?.positionValue?.latitude ?? 0, longitude: arConfig?.positionValue?.longitude ?? 0)
let location = CLLocation(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: -1.5)
    
// Load model
let model = MDLAsset(url: (self.arConfig?.models.first!)!)
model.loadTextures()
    
let modelNode: SCNNode = SCNNode(mdlObject: model.object(at: 0))
modelNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 15, y: 15, z: 15)
    
// Rotate
let orientation = modelNode.orientation
var glQuaternion = GLKQuaternionMake(orientation.x, orientation.y, orientation.z, orientation.w)
let multiplier = GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis(90, 0, 1, 0)
glQuaternion = GLKQuaternionMultiply(glQuaternion, multiplier)
    
modelNode.orientation = SCNQuaternion(x: glQuaternion.x, y: glQuaternion.y, z: glQuaternion.z, w: glQuaternion.w)
    
// Create location node and add the model node to it
let locationNode = LocationNode(location: location)
locationNode.addChildNode(modelNode)

// Add the location node for a given location which includes the model to the scene
sceneLocationView.addLocationNodeWithConfirmedLocation(locationNode: locationNode)
```

Can anyone lead me in the right direction here?

Comment: Have you found any solution because i need same thing?

Comment: Yes, the answer from Gerrit worked for me. I accepted it again as it somehow got removed in the past @RakeshPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Location Node is missing following configuration:

```
locationNode.continuallyUpdatePositionAndScale = true
locationNode.continuallyAdjustNodePositionWhenWithinRange = true
locationNode.scaleRelativeToDistance = true
```

This will allow the node to actually reduce its scale when it's further away or upscale it when it's closer.

In addition, adding the SCNNode containing the 3D model to the child nodes of your location node does not work because the child nodes do not inherit the configuration of its parent. To fix that the 3D model node has to be either of type `LocationNode` or of a type which inherits from `LocationNode`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ARGeoAnchor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/argeoanchor) seems very suited to your needs.

> A geographic anchor (also known as location anchor) identifies a specific area in the world that the app can refer to in an AR experience. As a user moves around the scene, the session updates a location anchor’s transform based on the anchor’s coordinate and the device’s compass heading.

> `init(name: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, altitude: CLLocationDistance)`
>
> Initializes a named location anchor with the given coordinates and altitude.

Comment: I've looked into that but unfortunately the localization imagery is only available for specific areas.